# Equivalent of "Born to X, Forced to Y" snowclone

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm looking for an equivalent to phrases such as "Born to fish, forced to save the world" (for use in a social media bio or etc., so usage of internet slang is fine), but I'm doubtful that the "born to, forced to" pattern has the same impact when transliterated (釣るために生まれた already sounds quite awkward to me).

Does such a pattern exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That meme has never been popular in Japan. It's possible to translate it as an ordinary sentence, but it's probably impossible to convert it to a Japanese joke that has a similar fixed pattern.

For example, if we give up on it being a snowclone, an equivalent of "Born to fish, forced to work" might be something like the following:

- 釣りをするために生まれ、生きるために働く
- 生まれながらの釣り人、現実は永遠の社畜
- 釣りのための人生、生きるための労働
- 我が人生は釣りのため、我が労働は金のため
- 釣り師として生を受け、今は単なる会社の犬
- 釣りだけして生きるのが理想、労働だけして生きるのが現実
- 理想は[太公望](https://gogen-yurai.jp/taikoubou/)、現実は社畜

I tried to make it as humorous and interesting as possible as an SNS profile, though there is no guarantee as to how far I have succeeded.